# Data never stops loading - List.Buffer/List.PositionOf problem - Power Query M

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

[image]I'm trying to effectively perform a "Vlookup" in Power Query to get the Region and the Specialist for a given row (based on the "Location" column of the "export" table). See attached screenshot.

Approach #1:
I've tried using the `List.PositionOf()` function to then get an index to then pull in the corresponding Region/Specialist, as you'll see in the M language below. The problem here is that to apply this change to the query never ends, the data just keeps loading, well past the total amount of data that I have in my source files (I've let it load past 2 GB, when the data is in the 100 MB range in total). To try and solve this, I've used the `List.Buffer()` function, but to no avail.

Approach #2:
I attempted using a merge to simply join the two tables that contain the Region/Specialist information, but that results in a "Data.Format Error - can't convert to number" for every non-number type column of the new merged table. What is causing this?

I'm fine using either method, if you have a solution to make either work.

Code:

```
let
     Source = Folder.Files("G:\Trintech\Trintech Export Files\Trintech Daily Bank Exports"),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".csv")),
    #"Filtered Hidden Files1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows1", each [Attributes]?[Hidden]? <> true),
    #"Filtered Hidden Files2" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Hidden Files1", each [Attributes]?[Hidden]? <> true),
    #"Invoke Custom Function1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Hidden Files2", "Transform File", each #"Transform File"([Content])),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Invoke Custom Function1", {"Name", "Source.Name"}),
    #"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Renamed Columns1", {"Source.Name", "Transform File"}),
    #"Expanded Table Column1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns1", "Transform File", Table.ColumnNames(#"Transform File"(#"Sample File"))),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Table Column1",{{"Source.Name", type text}, {"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type text}, {"Column4", type number}, {"Column5", type number}, {"Column6", type date}, {"Column7", type date}, {"Column8", Int64.Type}, {"Column9", type text}, {"Column10", type number}, {"Column11", type date}, {"Column12", type number}, {"Column13", type text}, {"Column14", type text}, {"Column15", type text}, {"Column16", type any}, {"Column17", type number}, {"Column18", type any}, {"Column19", type any}, {"Column20", type any}, {"Column21", type text}, {"Column22", type any}, {"Column23", type any}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"Column1", "Internal/External"}, {"Column2", "DR/CR"}, {"Column3", "Transaction Type"}, {"Column4", "Amount"}, {"Column5", "Location"}, {"Column6", "Post Date"}, {"Column7", "Effective Date"}, {"Column8", "Account"}, {"Column9", "Account Number"}, {"Column10", "Bai Code"}, {"Column11", "Match Date"}, {"Column12", "Match Group ID"}, {"Column13", "Match Rule"}, {"Column14", "Match Technique"}, {"Column15", "Matched/Unmatched"}, {"Column16", "Order ID"}, {"Column17", "Reference 10"}, {"Column18", "Reference 5"}, {"Column19", "Reference 6"}, {"Column20", "Reference 7"}, {"Column21", "Reference 8"}, {"Column22", "Reference 9"}, {"Column23", "Reference Number"}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Location Position", each List.PositionOf(List.Buffer(Sheet1[Store]),List.Buffer([Location]))),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Sheet1.Region", each List.Buffer(Sheet1[Region]){List.Buffer([Location Position])}),
    #"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Specialist Position", each List.PositionOf(List.Buffer(Sheet2[Region]),List.Buffer([Sheet1.Region]))),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom3", "Sheet2.Specialist", each List.Buffer(Sheet2[Specialist]){List.Buffer([Specialist Position])}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom2",{"Location Position", "Specialist Position"}),
    #"Replaced Errors" = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(#"Removed Columns", {{"Sheet2.Specialist", ""}}),
    #"Replaced Errors1" = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(#"Replaced Errors", {{"Sheet1.Region", ""}}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Replaced Errors1", {"Location"}, Sheet1, {"Store"}, "Sheet1", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Sheet1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Sheet1", {"Region"}, {"Sheet1.Region.1"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Sheet1", each true)
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, but there is no way for anyone to help you based on your question.  We don't know what the custom function is. We don't know what the raw data looks like that the code is running against. I'd suggest making up a simple sample input and desired output, and we can work with that

Comment: The solution was to include a step to replace errors in the columns I was merging on. Now "Approach #2" works and loads the data fine, merged and all.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to include a step to replace errors in the columns I was merging on. Now "Approach #2" works and loads the data fine, merged and all.

As I read elsewhere, it is often the case that no errors appear for a column until a merge or some other action is taken on the entire column because only a 1000 row preview is being checked for errors.